# How to upload a eclipse dynamic web project to a live server?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, web-hosting

I have developed a dynamic web project using eclipse and i am having a domain name and a web hoster. all i want to do is to upload my eclipse project to my web hosting site. Currently i am using html 5 template on my website but i want to upload my own project on it. I have heard that we can do it by using war file but i am not sure how to do it as my html 5 template contains many html page like index.html and it is more in size as compare to war file which i have exported. Please tell me i am totally clueless about it

Answer (score 0):

Your web host needs to support Java and some Servlet container. If they don't already have those two things installed, you'll need to install them yourself. Once that is done, in Eclipse, you will need to export your project in the form of a `.war` file and place it in the appropriate folder of your Servlet Container. For example, with Tomcat, you would place it in its `/webapps` directory. You then start your Servlet Container. Your web application will be up and running.

Answer (score 0):

If your web project includes Java web technologies such as Servlets and JSP, you will need to

1. Build your war file first either with Ant, or Maven.
2. Then you can upload the war file to your web server using some type of deployment tool that is usually available on the hosting web server. For Apache Tomcat for example, you can use the Tomcat Manager tool to deploy your war file.